# Correlated subquery - guidance

Tags: mysql

I'm just wondering if anyone could help me understand why this isn't working:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz6rd.jpg)

The first query is showing the Min order date. I don't understand why this order's details still show up (top row) in the second query when I'm specifying to show everything > than this date. (screenshot attached)

Any advice would be much appreciated. Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the both the SQL and output as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in your subquery you did not specify the `where` condition and so that subquery can return a date that is earlier than the one you got in the first query.

So in the subquery also add:

```
where CustomerKey = '11000'
```

Comment: Oh nice thanks so much for the prompt response! and yes that worked perfectly :) - I have 100's of customer in this database so lets say I don't want to fiter to a specific customer but want to display all orders for all customers after the first order date for each, what would I need to specify here? Thanks again